# PHP and CSS percentage bar not displaying div

Tags: php, css

I made a percentage bar (just a simple one to get the idea). I made a CSS rule and a short PHP block of code. For some reason, the larger bar will not display. The smaller one that shows how much space is used will, however. What am I missing here?

PHP:

```
$free = disk_free_space("F:");
$total = disk_total_space("F:");
$used = $total - $free;
$value = $used;
$max = $total;
$scale = 4.0;
if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($value * 100) / $max; }
else { $percent = 0; }
if ( $percent > 100) { $percent = 100; }
```

CSS:

```
.percentbar {
background-color: #CCC;
border: solid 2px #000;
height:16px;
}
.percentbar div {
background-color: #F90;
height: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="percentbar" style="width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px">
<div style="width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;">
</div>
</div>
```

The first div in the HTML is not being displayed, while the subsidiary div is being displayed.

Comment: `var_dump($percent)` what do you get?

Comment: May be you are not getting the value of $percent.So try to display it and check whther $percent have any value

Comment: @martriay With var_dump($percent) it gives what I expected: float(31.631995391554). I accidentally deleted parts of my CSS, and I'm guessing when I remade it I screwed up somewhere along the lines because this was working before.

Comment: @E-swizz that same HTML + CSS worked for me with hardcoded values, so you should verify the PHP output. http://jsfiddle.net/eF9P5/ . Try `$percentvar = round(100 * $scale); var_dump($percentbar);`

Comment: I've been dumping all of my variables out, and they all come out fine. Plus, this was just working yesterday. I then deleted this part of the CSS, keeping the PHP and HTML intact. When I originally made this there was some CSS value I added that fixed the larger div not displaying, but I can't remember what it was. I will continue echoing out the variables, but I am 99% sure it is the CSS: everything on the PHP side checks out.

Comment: Are there any syntax errors in your CSS before those styles?  Open a DOM inspector and check what the calculated width on that div is.  The CSS you've posted looks perfect.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I don't think your problem is css.</del>
If you put the same width for both divs, you aren´t going to see one of them.

So you have to be sure about the php values you are printing on width. If they are the same for both divs or incorrect, the first div may be apparently not being displayed

---

I have tested it just now with exactly the same values you are saying and it works perfectly. Check if there can be another css overriding this one

[image: Percent bar]

Comment: I checked both PHP values for both bars. I get 127px for the percent used, and 400px for the larger div bar. What am I missing???

Comment: I have tested it just now with exactly the same values you are saying and it works perfectly.

Check if there can be another css overriding this one

Comment: ...How it happened? NO CLUE. But when I deleted the comment <!-- BEGIN BETA CSS --> several lines above it, the problem was fixed. I'm sorry for wasting your time over a stupid issue like this, but thanks for your help anyway. If I could help you in return, I would... but as you can see I can't write code to save my life.

Comment: Ok man. Shit happens.
If you could mark my answer as useful i would appreciate

Comment: I would but I just joined and lack sufficient "reputation" to do so.

Answer (score 0):

$percent probably would always have a value less than 100 because $value/$max is between 0 and 1, multiplying it with 100 would always get less than 100. The smaller bar might just be on top of the larger bar.

Comment: I echoed out $percent already and I get what I should: roughly 31%.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .percentbar {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height:16px;
    }
    .percentbar div {
    background-color: #F90;
    height: 16px;
    }
</style>
<html>
<?php

$free = disk_free_space("F:");
$total = disk_total_space("F:");
$used = $total - $free;
$value = $used;
$max = $total;
$scale = 4.0;
if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($value * 100) / $max; }
else { $percent = 0; }
if ( $percent > 100) { $percent = 100; }
?>

<div class="percentbar" style="width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px">
<div style="width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;">
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

this one displays:

[image]

may be you put the php code under the percentbar div that is why its not displaying the gray bar:

```
<style>
    .percentbar {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height:16px;
    }
    .percentbar div {
    background-color: #F90;
    height: 16px;
    }
</style>
<html>


<div class="percentbar" style="width:<?php echo round(100 * $scale); ?>px">
<div style="width:<?php echo round($percent * $scale); ?>px;">
</div>
</div>
<?php

$free = disk_free_space("F:");
$total = disk_total_space("F:");
$used = $total - $free;
$value = $used;
$max = $total;
$scale = 4.0;
if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($value * 100) / $max; }
else { $percent = 0; }
if ( $percent > 100) { $percent = 100; }
?>
</html>
```